# Unable to launch url from cypress

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

Sample code:

```
'''///<reference types = 'Cypress'/>
import LoginPage from '../PageObjects/LoginPage'

describe('Test suite',function(){
    
   it('Verify login', function()
   {
     const loginPage = new LoginPage
     cy.visit('https://stagingURL.com/login/')  <<<<<<<<<<
     loginPage.getUsernameField().type('user1')
     loginPage.getPasswordField().type('pass1')
     loginPage.getSubmitButton().click()   
    })
})'''
```

If I change URL to any other URL, cy.visit works. But it does not work for my staging envt url.
Fails due "secure connection failed" error when launched from Firefox.
And fails due to "This page isn't working" error when launched from chrome.

Comment: Can you open the this url `https://stagingURL.com/login/` normally on the firefox browser ?

Comment: Yes, I can open it normally through all the browsers as well as via selenium webdriver but not through cypress.

Comment: what is your cypress version?

Comment: Also can you run the test in CLI using the command `node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser firefox --headless`

Comment: Cypress version is 6.2.1 
Now, I tried to do the same thing from my local machine and I was able to do it..
This is probably some configuration issue on remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `new LoginPage` does not have parenthesis after. It will need to be `new LoginPage()`.

Comment: I added parenthesis. Issue persists. :(

Comment: I've gone to the site in just the browser and it is not working. You might want to check to see if it is actually running or you have to boot up a server of some kind to get it going.

Comment: This is not exact url. I am not permitted to share the details of the project hence posted dummy url here.